# chrome keeps redirecting because of HSTS

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, web, hsts, http-status-code-307

I have implemented a simple static server like this in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` that will serve a bunch of files

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name www.x.app x.app;
    root /usr/share/app/front-end/build;
    location / {

        index index.html;
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
            
    }

}
```

but when i browse http://www.x.app will immediately get redirected to https://www.x.app but i want to browse as http and i searched a lot and find out the `Non-Authoritative-Reason: HSTS` header that chrome gets ( that will redirect me using `307 Internal Redirect` ) there is security occur because of "HSTS"
the answers said that use `add_header  Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0";` in NginX Configurations but it didn't work
P.S.1: i cleared my chrome cache and also doesn't work
P.S.2:

*Querying HSTS/PKP domain* in chrome:

```
Found:
static_sts_domain: app
static_upgrade_mode: FORCE_HTTPS
static_sts_include_subdomains: true
static_sts_observed: 1613773712
static_pkp_domain:
static_pkp_include_subdomains:
static_pkp_observed:
static_spki_hashes:
dynamic_sts_domain:
dynamic_upgrade_mode: UNKNOWN
dynamic_sts_include_subdomains:
dynamic_sts_observed:
dynamic_sts_expiry:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Google launched the .app top level domain they announced it will be only be available over HTTPS as it will have HSTS preloaded in Chrome’s (and other browsers) code, rather than depending on sites configuring it as such in their webserver a:

https://blog.google/technology/developers/introducing-app-more-secure-home-apps-web/

> A key benefit of the .app domain is that security is built in—for you and your users. The big difference is that HTTPS is required to connect to all .app websites, helping protect against ad malware and tracking injection by ISPs, in addition to safeguarding against spying on open WiFi networks. Because .app will be the first TLD with enforced security made available for general registration, it’s helping move the web to an HTTPS-everywhere future in a big way.

So you need to use another domain name if you do not want to use HTTPS. Note that .dev is in the same situation.

Comment: Yes, i found that out last night but didn't know about .dev.
Many thanks for your answer Barry.